# Can a database column be configured to allow NULL even if the property type is not nullable?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

This question is related to [EF Core Issue #13079: Columns for nested owned types don't allow NULL although owned by derived entity](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13079). But it may be of interest more generally (e.g. if an existing not-well-modeled database has to be matched). At least for nested owned types within derived entities with TPH it would provide a way to configure the database such that its schema by now is like it will be after the linked issue is fixed:
Can a database column for a property be configured to allow `NULL` even if the property type is not nullable? If yes, how?

Given the following type:

```
public class SubData
{
    public Int32 Prop { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to manually configure the database column for `SubData.Prop` to allow `NULL`?

`IsRequired(false)` cannot be used because `Int32` is not nullable. If needed we may assume that the name of the column is known to be, say, `Data_SubData_Prop`, and that the name of the table is, say, `Entity`. Probably it could be done using SQL `ALTER COLUMN`. But can it be done by Fluent API, too?

Comment: I think it's specific to TPH implementation. For general case it doesn't make sense even if it was possible - how you will read null value into non nullable field?

Comment: I think you should try to expose your use case here, because even if this can be done manually I wouldn't recommend it, you'll probably have issues to maintain this over time.

Comment: @IvanStoev: You're probably right. But since there is no alternative to TPH right now it is of interest at least for that case.

Comment: @Roxtar: My use case are nested owned types within derived entities. I condensed the real world situation into a code sample and opend [EF Core Issue #13079](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13079) with it.

Comment: It's not possible anyway. The point was that it cannot be supported in general, and in case of TPH or similar it needs special infrastructure support for something which is logically not nullable, but needs to use nullable table column. And when the infrastructure contains bugs, there is nothing you can do until it gets fixed in the infrastructure code. Which means you have to wait for the issue you opened to be resolved.

Comment: @GeroIwan theoretically it’s not possible

Comment: @IvanStoev, @viveknuna: There are a lot of public classes and methods in the several `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Xyz.Internal` namespaces. Their documentation is like _"This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases."_ This wouldn't bother me for a workaround until the issue is resolved. However, without documentation it's hard to find out whether there is a suitable method that supports this infrastructure problem. But I thought, that maybe somebody else knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to manually configure the database column for SubData.Prop to allow NULL?

Yes, it is by using SQL, e.g. (for Microsoft SQL Server)

```
if ( context.Database.EnsureCreated() )
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Entity ALTER COLUMN Data_SubData_Prop int NULL");
}
```

> But can it be done by Fluent API, too?

Unfortunately, I don't know. (See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980946/can-a-database-column-be-configured-to-allow-null-even-if-the-property-type-is-n/52034186#comment91018212_51980946) on the question regarding [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Xyz.Internal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=efcore-2.1&term=internal) namespaces.)

Comment: Since there seems to be no other possibility (e.g. by Fluent API) I'll use this SQL approach as workaround for the [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13079) (and therefore accept my own answer).